# cURL failonerror, fails and doesn't record any error

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm using the libcurl library in PHP to create a website scraper...the scraper gets hung up randomly, and so I've enabled verbose error logging using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
            CURLOPT_STDERR => $flog` which is fine, but the scraper is getting hung up so I've enabled one more setting `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true` now the scraper stops abruptly when it hits an error but no error is recorded in the CURLOPT_STDERR which is being stored in a textfile in the temporary folder.  If I disable FAILONERROR it just hangs there and I don't get any errors, all success responses.  Anyone have any idea on how to log the errors that occur with failonerror, or where they might be stored?

Answer (score 1):

Did you ensured settings in your php.ini ? I think you have to check whether error echoing is turned off.
[php-ini-error-settings](http://www.phpknowhow.com/configuration/php-ini-error-settings/)

Comment: I have disabled error echo output via ini_set('display_errors', 0); from within the scraper, but I do have php error logging enabled and the php error log doesn't catch the error either

Comment: I reccommend you to check this link
http://www.julianbez.com/blog/2006/02/19/how-to-set-up-error-logging-with-php/